# XPath Scrapy Result issues - OR statement?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the "Team Batting" table on this: http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2013.shtml web page. I am having two issues.

1. I am only getting player rank up to 34, not the total of 43. I have no idea why this is happening. Nothing in the code looks different from 34 to 35.
2. The player position only goes to DH, then it repeats it all over again, giving everyone after the first DH the same positions. The first 10 positions have a "Strong" tag, so I made an OR statement to do both "Strong" and not strong. Apparently that didn't work right.

Here is the XPATH code:

```
    item ['rank'] = stats.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()')[count].extract()
    item ['position'] = stats.select(('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/strong/text()') or ('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()'))[count].extract()
    item ['name'] = stats.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/a/text()')[count].extract()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Issue 1:**

Your XPath is right and I've tested it and get all the 43 nodes.

```
>>> res = hxs.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract()
>>> res
[u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'10', u'11', u'12', u'13', u'14', u'15', u'16', u'17', u'18', u'19', u'20', u'21', u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'26', u'27', u'28', u'29', u'30', u'31', u'32', u'33', u'34', u'35', u'36', u'37', u'38', u'39', u'40', u'41', u'42', u'43']
>>> len(res)
43
```

I think you get 34 for you slice the result with `[count]`. So you get only part of the result.

```
>>> len(hxs.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()')[:34].extract())
34
```

**Issue2:**

Such a `or` certainly won't work. You can just change a bit of your XPath to get the text without concern about there is a strong or not.

```
>>> res = hxs.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[2]//text()').extract()
                                                                 ^
```

Use `//` instead of `/`. This will retrieve all the descendant text nodes. You can see the result:

```
>>> res
[u'C', u'1B', u'2B', u'SS', u'3B', u'LF', u'CF', u'RF', u'DH', u'OF', u'IF', u'UT', u'C', u'OF', u'UT', u'3B', u'UT', u'UT', u'IF', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P', u'P']
>>> len(res)
43
```

**Snippet I use:**

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2013.shtml')
>>> hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(text=f.read())
>>> rank = hxs.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract()
>>> position = hxs.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[2]//text()').extract()
>>> name = hxs.select('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/a/text()').extract()
```

**Edit:**

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(text=f.read())
divs = hxs.select('//div[@class="table_container"]')
for div in divs:
    table = div.select('./table')
    item['rank'] = table.select('./tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract()
    ...
```

Comment: I am still having issues with #1. I removed the count, but now it is putting a Rank 1-44 dictionary in each line. Also, it scrapes every player in that table, and then starts to repeat, so it has 77 lines.

Example of a partial line: {"position": "P", "name": "Andrew Miller", "rank": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5",

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Is there something wrong with my parser code? " def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    stats = hxs.select('//div')
    count = 0
    items = []
    
    for stat in stats:"

Comment: There is no need for the `stats = hxs.select('//div')`. I directly use `hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response); hxs.select(YOURXPATH)` and it succeed as you see. There is only one table in the page.

Comment: I changed it to that, and I get this error: Name 'hxs' is not defined.  Here is my code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rk29kotd09kioeg/mlbref_spyder.py

Comment: Notice the indentation. The XPath select statements should be in the `parse` scope right?

Comment: Then it tells me that HtmlXPathSelector is not iterable. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: I have updated my answer and posted my snippet. You may check.@AngryWhopper

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rk29kotd09kioeg/mlbref_spyder.py  If I remove the 'for hxs in hxs', and fix indention, I only get one player, and it still adds the rank dictionary into that one line (like in my first comment).

Comment: The four table are of different id. Your XPath is not able to extract them all once.

Comment: Edited my answer and add the for. I just give part of it. But it should work.@AngryWhopper

Comment: The issue with your edits is that it puts the "Rank" 1-44, and all of the positions in one dictionary on the same line together. What I am trying to do, is have a one dictionary for each "Rank", "Position", etc.  Example: {'rank': u'1', 'position': u'1B'}   I got this to work on another site. I am not sure why this one is so hard.


[{"rank": 1}

Comment: No XPath related. A good question for a new post. Just post the three dict you get and then give what you want. A lot of persons can give nice answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help zhangyangyu!